# Can't click custom UICollectionViewCell contents

Tags: ios, swift

I have a [view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCmcy.png) with a collection view of xib files. Each of the [xib files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUxr2.png) has a collection view that is overlaid on a UIView. Custom collection view cells are formatted on another separate [xib file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kwjm.png) When I tap on the custom view contents, neither `didSelectItemAt indexPath` or pressing of a button illicits any response.

I am suspecting that it may be due to an invisible view that prevents the cells from being tapped ([from user interface inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM7h2.png)). The frontmost view appears to have constraints that are of type `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints`, however I have set all views that are set programmatically with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

I believe I have followed all correct steps to add custom xib files to the views and all necessary delegates and dataSources have also been set correctly. The screen is supposed to look like this in the [end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oy5G.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing that I would try is adding `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true` to your custom UICollectionViewCell class.

You can do that programmatically inside of your custom collection view cell class by adding:

```
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```